# accumulation points of intersection of two open sets

Tags: general-topology, analysis

Let $A$ and $B$ be open subsets of $\mathbb{R}^2$.

If $0 \in A$ and $0 \in \mbox{acc}(B)$,
then show that

$ 0 \in \mbox{acc}(A \cap B),$

where acc$(B)$ is the set of accumulation points of $B$.

Comment: Let $B \subset \mathbb{R}^2$. A point $x \in \mathbb{R}^2$ is called accumulation point of $B$ if each neighborhood of $x$ contains infinitely many points of $B$.

Comment: I have tried the following:

Comment: Since $0 \in A$ and $A$ is open, therefore, there exists an open disc of radius $\epsilon >0$ centered at $0$ such that $D(0,\epsilon) \subset A$. Now as $0$ is accumulation point of $B$, then by thedefinition of accumulatiuon point there exists an infinite subset $B'$ of $B$ such that $B' \subset D(0,\epsilon) \subset A$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $O$ be any open neighbourhood of $0$. Then $O \cap A$ is also an open neighbourhood of $0$ so contains infinitely many points of $B$, which are points of $A \cap B$, and so a fortiori does $O$. So $0$ is an accumulation point of $A \cap B$.

In one line $$\aleph_0 \le |(O \cap A) \cap B|= |(O \cap (A \cap B)|$$

No specifics of metrics or the plane are needed.

Comment: Here we need to take $0 \in A$. I'm not able to get it.

Answer (score 0):

Note that for any open disk $D$ with center $0$ and radius $\epsilon >0$, there exists an open disk $D^*\subset A$ with center $0$ and radius $0< \delta < \epsilon$. Now, use the fact that $D^*$ is open, contains $0$, and $0\in \text{acc}(B)$.

Comment: Please elaborate. I'm not able to understand how $0 \in$ acc($A\cap B$).

Comment: As a result of my last sentence: $D^*$ contains infinitely many points of $B$, and these point are also in $A\cap B$, since $D^* \subset A$. Therefore, every open disk $D$ with center $0$ contains infinitely many points of $A\cap B$ (i.e. $0$ satisfies the definition of accumulation points of $A\cap B$). You already properly answered your question in the comments under your question.